# DSolve returns a complex integration with K[1] and K[3], when I try to solve an ordinary differential equation. How to plot the function?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

When I solve this ordinary differential equation as follows, a very complex result can be obtained.

```
DSolve[D[f[x], x] + f[x]/x + f[x]*D[f[x], x]/x + 2*(f[x])^2/x^2 - f[x]*D[f[x], {x, 2}] + (D[f[x], x])^2 == 0, f[x], x]
```

The output is

```
{{f[x] -> -(E^(
  C[2] - Inactive[Integrate][(
    2 f[K[3]]^2 + f[K[3]] K[3] + C[1]^2 f[K[3]]^2 K[3]^2 + 
     2 C[1] f[K[3]]^2 K[
       3]^2 Inactive[Integrate][(-2 f[K[1]]^2 - f[K[1]] K[1] - 
        f[K[1]] K[1] Derivative[1][f][K[1]] - 
        K[1]^2 Derivative[1][f][K[1]])/(
       f[K[1]]^2 K[1]^2), {K[1], 1, K[3]}] + 
     f[K[3]]^2 K[
       3]^2 Inactive[Integrate][(-2 f[K[1]]^2 - f[K[1]] K[1] - 
        f[K[1]] K[1] Derivative[1][f][K[1]] - 
        K[1]^2 Derivative[1][f][K[1]])/(
       f[K[1]]^2 K[1]^2), {K[1], 1, K[3]}]^2 + 
     f[K[3]] K[3] Derivative[1][f][K[3]] + 
     K[3]^2 Derivative[1][f][K[3]])/(
    f[K[3]]^2 K[
      3]^2 (C[1] + 
       Inactive[Integrate][(-2 f[K[1]]^2 - f[K[1]] K[1] - 
         f[K[1]] K[1] Derivative[1][f][K[1]] - 
         K[1]^2 Derivative[1][f][K[1]])/(
        f[K[1]]^2 K[1]^2), {K[1], 1, K[3]}])), {K[3], 1, x}])/(C[
    1] + Inactive[
      Integrate][(-2 f[K[1]]^2 - f[K[1]] K[1] - 
        f[K[1]] K[1] Derivative[1][f][K[1]] - 
        K[1]^2 Derivative[1][f][K[1]])/(f[K[1]]^2 K[1]^2), {K[1], 
      1, x}]))}}
```

This solution contains not only K[1] and K[3], but also the unknown function f[x]. How to get the analytical solution? How to plot the function f[x]? Thanks a lot!

Comment: (1) The presence of `f` in the solution suggests a bug to me. (2) You need to substitute numeric values for `C[1]` etc. See documentation for `DSolve` > Scope > Basic Uses, second example (the first that uses `Plot[]`. (3) The `Inactive[Integrate]` should be replaced by `NIntegrate`, but not before the other issues are dealt with. Might be tricky.

Comment: Is there any chance that you know a couple of plausible initial conditions that this must satisfy? If those are good then that might lead to a much simpler result that could be inspected to see if the solution is plausible. I tried multiplying both sides by x^2 to eliminate the denominators and that didn't seem to help.

Comment: @Michael E2 Thank you very much for your attention.The last two points you mentioned, I get your intention. However, how to solve this bug about the first point? Does it mean that the differential equation cannot be solved analytically, but only numerically?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think it is a bug also. May be should send to support@wolfram.com.

Copied the ode to Maple, got the solution, copied the solution back to Mathematica and verified it there, it verifies:

```
ode := MmaTranslator:-FromMma(`D[f[x], x] + f[x]/x + f[x]*D[f[x], x]/x + 2*(f[x])^2/x^2 -f[x]*D[f[x], {x, 2}] + (D[f[x], x])^2 == 0`);
dsolve(ode)
```

[image]

In Mathematica:

```
ode=D[f[x],x]+f[x]/x+f[x]*D[f[x],x]/x+2*(f[x])^2/x^2-f[x]*D[f[x],{x,2}]+(D[f[x],x])^2==0;
sol=f->Function[{x},-1/(C[1]*x)+C[2]/x*Exp[-1/2*C[1]*x^2]]
ode/.sol//Simplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

> How to plot the function?

You can not plot the solution as it contains unknown constants. Need initial conditions.

Comment: Thank you very much!